# Qual a diferença entre criar um Socket via SocketFactory e criar um com new Socket?

Tags: java, socket

Estava estudando sobre Sockets e vi que algumas pessoas criavam sockets com o SocketFactory (javax).

**Eu sempre criei assim:** `Socket skt = new Socket(host, port);`

**No exemplo estava assim:**

```
Socket s = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(host, port);
```

Qual é a diferença entre essas duas formas de criar um socket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Factory pattern

A diferença básica é que em um você inicializa o objeto com o `new` e com o outro você utiliza o Factory pattern pra cuidar disso pra você.

De forma geral todos os padrões Factory (Simple Factory, Factory Method, Abstract Factory) encapsulam a criação de objetos. O padrão Factory Method por sua vez encapsula a criação de objetos, no entanto, a diferença é que neste padrão encapsula-se a criação de objetos deixando as subclasses decidirem quais objetos criar.

O Diagrama de classe abaixo mostra mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento do padrão Factory Method.

[image]
<sub>(fonte: [web-03.net](http://videos.web-03.net/artigos/Higor_Medeiros/PadraoFactoryMethod/PadraoFactoryMethod1.jpg))</sub>

No diagrama de classe acima temos a classe de criador abstrata que é a Creator que define um método fábrica abstrata que as subclasses implementam para criar um produto (factoryMethod) e pode possuir um ou mais métodos com seus devidos comportamentos que chamarão o factoryMethod. Normalmente o método factoryMethod do Creator também possui um Product abstrato que é produzido por uma subclasse (ConcreteCreator). Nota-se que cada ConcreteCreator produzirá seu próprio método de criação.

Segundo o GOF (Group Of Four) o padrão Factory Method é: “Um padrão que define uma interface para criar um objeto, mas permite às classes decidirem qual classe instanciar. O Factory Method permite a uma classe deferir a instanciação para subclasses”.

## Vantagem do Factory Pattern

Com o padrão Factory Method podemos encapsular o código que cria objetos. É muito comum termos classes que instanciam classes concretas e essa parte do código normalmente sofre diversas modificações, portanto nesses casos usamos um Factory Method que encapsula esse comportamento de instanciação.

Usando o Factory Method temos o nosso código de criação em um objeto ou método, evitando assim a duplicação e além disso temos um local único para fazer manutenção. O padrão também nos dá um código flexível e extensível para o futuro.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-factory-method-em-java/26348